# How to use wild card character to search for s3 file using S3KeySensor in airflow

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, mwaa

Hello I am using S3KeySensor to look for parquet files created in specific partition. As the file names are generated from spark like (part-00499-e91c1af8-4352-4de9*), what should be the bucket_key ? Below code is failing.

```
    ex:bucket_key=f"inbound/phix/empnf/datasetdate={var_ds_date}/*.parquet"

s3_data_filechk=S3KeySensor(
         task_id='s3_data_filechk',
         bucket_name=data_bucket_name,
         bucket_key=f"inbound/phix/empnf/datasetdate={var_ds_date}/*.parquet/",
         timeout=60 * 30, # timeout in 30 minutes 
         poke_interval=60 * 5 # (seconds); checking file in every five minutes
     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `S3KeySensor` has parameter [`wildcard_match`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/602abe8394fafe7de54df7e73af56de848cdf617/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/sensors/s3.py#L74): whether the bucket_key should be interpreted as a Unix wildcard pattern. You can use it to set the logic you wish.

Example:

```
sensor=S3KeySensor(
         ...
         bucket_key="*.parquet",
         wildcard_match=True
     )
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks.